# Which API should I use?

Tags: paypal-adaptive-payments, instant, paypal

I am new with paypal.

After searching for info it seems paypal has a lot of technologies, APIs etc to be consumed and I cannot choose to right one for my case

My business case:

Simple marketplace android application with 2 main actors:

1. Seller
2. Buyer

Actions:

1. When buyer want to buy something via marketplace -> he pays via own paypal account to seller (buyer can see paypal page and authorize payment)
2. Seller automatically send fee payment to marketplace's paypal account (seller does not need any time autorize payment to marketplace, it should be automatically after buyer send money to seller)

Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to get that done depending on the experience you would like for all parties involved.

PayPal would recommend that you use the [Adaptive Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) for this because it's exactly the sort of thing they built it for.  Specifically, you could setup a [chained payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/?mark=chained%20payment).  That will automatically split the payment between the seller and the marketplace / app owner.

I personally don't like the Adaptive Payments checkout experience, so I prefer to build the same functionality with [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/).

For this, though, you would need to have the sellers that sign up with your marketplace create a billing agreement with the app (marketplace) so that you can trigger payments on their behalf.

Then you would [build a reference transaction payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/) to yourself from the seller account any time you need to.  So this could be as each transaction happens, or you could tally up some number of transactions and only process the reference transaction payment to yourself when the total reaches some amount, or do it once per week / month, or whatever you want to do in that case.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I have to check both with 2 POC

Comment: Hi Andrew,
Seller to be able to sell via marketplace needs to provide his "paypal email" - automatically. how can I get sellers's email of his paypal account?

Need something like this:

Marketplace ask seller to login to paypal and grant permittions for chain payments
Paypal provides to marketplace seller's email
Marketplace uses sellers's paypal email for adaptive api calls
How to reach this behavior?

Comment: Relatively to prev comment: in case of adaptive api flow: how to obtain  paypal email of seller?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Express Checkout as your payment solution.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/express-checkout/

EC provides mobilized checkout page, and you do not need to apply for special approvals. And by setting PAYMENTREQUEST_n_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID in SetExpressCheckout API, you may achieve parallel payments easily.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-parallelPayments/
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: Yes, it supports parallel payments, but keep in mind that means the buyer will be able to see that split happening. This can cause confusion and lead some to cancel their checkout if they aren't expecting that.  So with what I had outlined in my answer you would use the SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID parameter, but simply to mark the account the single payment should go to, and then you can use the billing agreement with that account to pull the payments owed to you for commission.  If it doesn't matter that the buyer sees the split, though, setting up the parallel payment would indeed be the best.

Comment: phillixzk, how to obtain paypal email of specific account (seller in my case)? I need it when set receiver for adaptive api. In this way sellers can enable marketplace to performs payments to paypal accounts... thank you!